# Qt: Why DPI decrease on increasing Scaling from OS

Tags: qt, dpi

I have a Qt application and I need to adapt the application (zoom-in/zoom-out) as the scaling changes from the OS in **Display Settings**.

I have read from Internet that:

> The standard DPI settings are 100% (96 DPI), 125% (120 DPI), and 150%
>   (144 DPI)

But, I am getting below DPI values when logged from the Qt application:

**Scale - Physical DPI X - Physical DPI Y**

100% - 158, 159

125% - 158, 159

150% - 79, 79

175% - 79, 79

So, as per the above values, the application text size has no difference for the 100% and 125% scale. Same behavior applies for 150% and 175%.

Below is the Qt code that I used:

```
    #include <QWidget>
    QApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);

    QWidget  widget;
    qInfo() << "Hello Qt";
    int dpiX = widget.physicalDpiX();
    int dpiY = widget.physicalDpiY();
    qInfo() << dpiX;
    qInfo() << dpiY;
```

Can anyone please guide? What I am trying to achieve is that the Qt application behaves (changes application size/ font size) depending on scaling set in **Display Settings** of the **OS**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I initially suggested using `QWindow::devicePixelRatio()` in this answer. However, as of Qt 5.12, this does not actually work correctly yet. Qt will avoid fractional scaling ratios due to a [bug in Qt's UI scaling implementation](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-53022). So for 125%, it will still return a 1.0 scaling factor. At 175%, it will return 2.0 instead of 1.75.

So for now, you should fall back to querying the DPI. However, query the *logical* DPI, *not* the physical DPI as you are doing now. Replace calls to `physicalDpi()` functions with calls to `logicalDpi()` ones. This should give you the standard 96/120/144 DPI reported by Microsoft Windows.

The previous part of the answer below can be used once Qt fixes the bug.

---

### Previous answer, applicable once Qt fixes their scaling bug

Query the scaling ratio directly, don't try to infer it from the DPI. You use [`QWindow::devicePixelRatio()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwindow.html#devicePixelRatio) for this. At 100% scaling, this will return 1.0. At 125% scaling, it will return 1.25. And so on. Since this is a scaling factor, you use it as a multiplier for your sizes.

You should call `devicePixelRatio()` on the window your widget is currently in. This is because different windows can be on different displays on multi-monitor setups.

The window the widget is in can be obtained with [`QWidget::windowHandle()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#windowHandle). This can return null if the widget is not a window. So you should probably write a small helper function that returns the correct DPR (Device Pixel Ratio) for a widget. It should take a QWidget as argument, and if `windowHandle()` returns null for the widget, walk up the parent tree, calling `windowHandle()` on each parent until it finds the first one that doesn't return null. Then return `windowHandle()->devicePixelRatio()`. This will be the correct DPR to use in that widget.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I tried to use devicePixelRatio() on my main application and I have no other widget in my application. For 100% and 125%, it return 1 while for 150% and 175%, it returns 2. EnableHighDpiScaling is ON.

Comment: @CodeZila Yeah, I updated the answer. For now, you'll have to use logical DPI until Qt fixes their scaling bug.